# Referencing in a private DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, date, jtable, defaulttablemodel

This is my code for a simple JTable with multiple searches and sorts. This may be a relatively simple problem but when I run the code I get an error when referncing "aData" and "aHeaders" in my "private DefaultTableModel model". Also after this small problem has been sorted will I encounter any other errors or exceptions? ie. NullPointerException

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
///////////
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
///////////
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JtableIe
{
    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Compare Tables");

    JPanel  firstPanel = new JPanel();

    JScrollPane myScrollTable;
    JTable myTable;
    JTextField srchFld1;
    JTextField srchFld2;
    TableRowSorter sorter;
    JLabel srchLbl1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel srchLbl2 = new JLabel();

    public void runGUI()
    {
        myMainWindow.setBounds(10, 10, 1296, 756);

        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        createFirstPanel();

        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);

        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createFirstPanel()
    {
        firstPanel.setLayout(null);

        srchLbl1.setLocation(0,0);
        srchLbl1.setSize(150,26);
        srchLbl1.setText("Name Search:");
        firstPanel.add(srchLbl1);

        srchLbl2.setLocation(660,0);
        srchLbl2.setSize(150,26);
        srchLbl2.setText("ID Search:");
        firstPanel.add(srchLbl2);

        String[] aHeaders = {"Name","ID","Number 1","Number 2","Time","Date"};
        Object[][] aData = new Object[15][6];
        myTable = new JTable(model);
        ///////Data////////
        aData[0][0] = "John";
        aData[0][1] = "JS96";
        aData[0][2] = "1";
        aData[0][3] = "186";
        aData[0][4] = "1h 23m";
        aData[0][5] = getJavaDate("12-11-2015");

        aData[1][0] = "David";
        aData[1][1] = "DB36";
        aData[1][2] = "2";
        aData[1][3] = "111852";
        aData[1][4] = "2h 55m";
        aData[1][5] = getJavaDate("12-11-2020");

        aData[2][0] = "Daniel";
        aData[2][1] = "DK73";
        aData[2][2] = "3";
        aData[2][3] = "2921";
        aData[2][4] = "1h 55m";
        aData[2][5] = getJavaDate("12-11-2014");

        aData[3][0] = "Janis";
        aData[3][1] = "JW84";
        aData[3][2] = "4";
        aData[3][3] = "6512";
        aData[3][4] = "12h 26m";
        aData[3][5] = getJavaDate("13-11-2015");

        aData[4][0] = "Adam";
        aData[4][1] = "AF98";
        aData[4][2] = "5";
        aData[4][3] = "7524";
        aData[4][4] = "5h 47m";
        aData[4][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[5][0] = "Matthew";
        aData[5][1] = "MB55";
        aData[5][2] = "6";
        aData[5][3] = "4989";
        aData[5][4] = "80h 30m";
        aData[5][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[6][0] = "Lewis";
        aData[6][1] = "LS23";
        aData[6][2] = "7";
        aData[6][3] = "56321";
        aData[6][4] = "880h 20m";
        aData[6][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[7][0] = "Mark";
        aData[7][1] = "ML49";
        aData[7][2] = "8";
        aData[7][3] = "97456";
        aData[7][4] = "8h 42m";
        aData[7][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[8][0] = "Josh";
        aData[8][1] = "JT67";
        aData[8][2] = "9";
        aData[8][3] = "82135";
        aData[8][4] = "56h 13m";
        aData[8][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[9][0] = "Oliver";
        aData[9][1] = "OC98";
        aData[9][2] = "10";
        aData[9][3] = "152";
        aData[9][4] = "9h 9m";
        aData[9][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[10][0] = "Tom";
        aData[10][1] = "TS97";
        aData[10][2] = "11";
        aData[10][3] = "100";
        aData[10][4] = "0h 0m";
        aData[10][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[11][0] = "Emma";
        aData[11][1] = "EBS74";
        aData[11][2] = "12";
        aData[11][3] = "200";
        aData[11][4] = "0h 30m";
        aData[11][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[12][0] = "Lucy";
        aData[12][1] = "LK02";
        aData[12][2] = "13";
        aData[12][3] = "256";
        aData[12][4] = "7h 00m";
        aData[12][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[13][0] = "Patrick";
        aData[13][1] = "PM38";
        aData[13][2] = "14";
        aData[13][3] = "258";
        aData[13][4] = "2h 00m";
        aData[13][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[14][0] = "Nicola";
        aData[14][1] = "NB70";
        aData[14][2] = "15";
        aData[14][3] = "987";
        aData[14][4] = "100h 56m";
        aData[14][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");
        //////////////

        myTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        sorter = new TableRowSorter(myTable.getModel());
        List sortKeys = new ArrayList();
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
        sorter.setComparator(2, new AlphanumComparator());
        sorter.setComparator(3, new AlphanumComparator());
        sorter.setComparator(4, new AlphanumComparator());
        setRenderers();
        myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);



        DefaultRowSorter sorter = (DefaultRowSorter) myTable.getRowSorter();


        myScrollTable = new JScrollPane(myTable); 
        myScrollTable.setSize(1296,756); 
        myScrollTable.setLocation(0,25); 
        System.out.println("Creating compare table");

        srchFld1 = new JTextField(10);
        srchFld1.setSize(550,26); 
        srchFld1.setLocation(100,0);
        srchFld1.setToolTipText("Enter Name");
        firstPanel.add(srchFld1);

        srchFld2 = new JTextField(10);
        srchFld2.setSize(550,26); 
        srchFld2.setLocation(740,0);
        srchFld2.setToolTipText("Enter ID");
        firstPanel.add(srchFld2);

        //////////////////////
        Document doc = srchFld1.getDocument();
        DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }
        };
        doc.addDocumentListener(listener);

        ///////////////
        Document docb = srchFld2.getDocument();
        DocumentListener listenerb = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }
        };
        docb.addDocumentListener(listenerb);
        ///////////////

        firstPanel.add(myScrollTable);
    }

    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(aData, aHeaders) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) 
        {
                return getValueAt(5, column).getClass();
        }
    };

    private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    private void setRenderers() {
        myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, new DateRenderer());
    }

    private Date getJavaDate(String s) {
        try 
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date d = sdf.parse(s);
            return d;
        } 

        catch (ParseException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(TableBasic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void newFilter()
    {
        RowFilter rf = null;
        try 
        {
            List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(srchFld1.getText(), 0));
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(srchFld2.getText(), 1));
            rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
        } 
        catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) 
        {
            return;
        }
        sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JtableIe ji = new JtableIe();
        ji.runGUI();
    }

    private class DateRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
    {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable myTable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(myTable, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (!(value instanceof Date)) {
                return this;
            }
            setText(DATE_FORMAT.format((Date) value));
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

AlphanumComparator code

```
 /*
 * The Alphanum Algorithm is an improved sorting algorithm for strings
 * containing numbers.  Instead of sorting numbers in ASCII order like
 * a standard sort, this algorithm sorts numbers in numeric order.
 *
 * The Alphanum Algorithm is discussed at http://www.DaveKoelle.com
 *
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 *
 */

import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * This is an updated version with enhancements made by Daniel Migowski,
 * Andre Bogus, and David Koelle
 *
 * To convert to use Templates (Java 1.5+):
 *   - Change "implements Comparator" to "implements Comparator<String>"
 *   - Change "compare(Object o1, Object o2)" to "compare(String s1, String s2)"
 *   - Remove the type checking and casting in compare().
 *
 * To use this class:
 *   Use the static "sort" method from the java.util.Collections class:
 *   Collections.sort(your list, new AlphanumComparator());
 */
public class AlphanumComparator implements Comparator
{
    private final boolean isDigit(char ch)
    {
        return ch >= 48 && ch <= 57;
    }

    /** Length of string is passed in for improved efficiency (only need to calculate it once) **/
    private final String getChunk(String s, int slength, int marker)
    {
        StringBuilder chunk = new StringBuilder();
        char c = s.charAt(marker);
        chunk.append(c);
        marker++;
        if (isDigit(c))
        {
            while (marker < slength)
            {
                c = s.charAt(marker);
                if (!isDigit(c))
                    break;
                chunk.append(c);
                marker++;
            }
        } else
        {
            while (marker < slength)
            {
                c = s.charAt(marker);
                if (isDigit(c))
                    break;
                chunk.append(c);
                marker++;
            }
        }
        return chunk.toString();
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        if (!(o1 instanceof String) || !(o2 instanceof String))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        String s1 = (String)o1;
        String s2 = (String)o2;

        int thisMarker = 0;
        int thatMarker = 0;
        int s1Length = s1.length();
        int s2Length = s2.length();

        while (thisMarker < s1Length && thatMarker < s2Length)
        {
            String thisChunk = getChunk(s1, s1Length, thisMarker);
            thisMarker += thisChunk.length();

            String thatChunk = getChunk(s2, s2Length, thatMarker);
            thatMarker += thatChunk.length();

            // If both chunks contain numeric characters, sort them numerically
            int result = 0;
            if (isDigit(thisChunk.charAt(0)) && isDigit(thatChunk.charAt(0)))
            {
                // Simple chunk comparison by length.
                int thisChunkLength = thisChunk.length();
                result = thisChunkLength - thatChunk.length();
                // If equal, the first different number counts
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < thisChunkLength; i++)
                    {
                        result = thisChunk.charAt(i) - thatChunk.charAt(i);
                        if (result != 0)
                        {
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                result = thisChunk.compareTo(thatChunk);
            }

            if (result != 0)
                return result;
        }

        return s1Length - s2Length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just reference "model" like that.

The order of your code is wrong. You first need to create the column array with column names and then the data array with data. Then you use these to variables to create your table model and add the table model to the table.

The code might be something like:

```
String[] aHeaders = {"Name","ID","Number 1","Number 2","Time","Date"};

Object[][] aData = new Object[15][6];

///////Data////////
aData[0][0] = "John";
aData[0][1] = "JS96";
aData[0][2] = "1";
aData[0][3] = "186";
aData[0][4] = "1h 23m";
aData[0][5] = getJavaDate("12-11-2015");
...

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(aData, aHeaders)
{
         @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) 
        {
            switch (column)
            {
                case 5: return Date.class;
                default: return Object.class;
            }
        }
};

myTable = new JTable( model );
```